# HiQPdf downloaded file does not contains Google Charts through IIS production

Tags: asp.net, iis, google-visualization, hiqpdf

I am using Asp.net c# library of HiQPdf to convert an aspx page into a pdf through url. when I run the website project from Visual studio in development environment, the converted pdf contains the charts as well. but on publishing it to IIS, the charts goes missing where as all other text in pdf is present.

I have tried both the approaches in HiQPdf ConvertUrlToFile() ConvertUrlToMemory(url)

anyone if faced such issue please help me.

Comment: I have same issue but in Amchart V4 [My issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638175)